# How to avoid that multiline text is clipped in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a GridPane which I'm filling with various graphical/textual elements.

For the text, single line labels gets the right size. The same happens to e.g. images
of various sizes (the grid is stretched to give space for the image).

However, for multiline text elements (a.e. a label containing text with newlines in it), it clips the element at one line height... How can I force an UI element (like a label) to take up enough space to display its content?

Here's some code (scala):

```
  val chatPanel = new GridPane {
    setFitToWidth(true)
    setFitToHeight(true)
    setManaged(true)
    setMaxWidth(10000)
    setMaxHeight(10000)
  }

   def sendTextInfoBlock(title:String,message:String) {
    val button = new Label(message) {
      // setWrapText(true)
      // setMinHeight(100) <- this works, but of course doesn't match the required height
    }
//    val button = new Button(message)
    chatPanel.add(button,1,row)
```

the message is a text with newlines, like `"this is a long\nand interresting\nmessage"`

Comment: Can you show us some code please?

Answer (score 0):

I gave up, stacked a VBox full of labels (one label per line of text), and just styled it
like a button. That worked well at least.